# WPF codebehind animation c#

Tags: c#, wpf

Can anyone help me how to create an animation thru codebehind using an  that will take a motion using a  defined controls?

please dont closed this i really need help on this....

```
<Image x:Name="imgMan" Source="/wpfUsrControlTower1;component/DependentResources/man.png" Stretch="Fill" Height="26.4">
<Image.RenderTransform>
<TransformGroup>
<ScaleTransform/>
<SkewTransform/>
<RotateTransform/>
<TranslateTransform/>
</TransformGroup>
</Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>

<Path x:Name="k3_r2" Visibility="Hidden" Fill="Transparent" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeDashArray="2 0 0 2" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Blue" Data="M570,190 L570,160 495,160 495,125 165,125 165,175" Height="65" Canvas.Left="165" Canvas.Top="125" Width="405"/>
```

Comment: Help you with what? You didn't tell us anything about the desired result. Have you tried anything yourself, or even read documentation about animations?

Comment: creating an animation in codebehind using <path> as its movement.... The image will move according to the <path> controlled designation points but in codebehind not in the xaml design...

Comment: But your research hasn't lead you to MatrixAnimationUsingPath or DoubleAnimationUsingPath?

Comment: I already create an animation for that but using the motion path that will automatically create a storyboard on the xaml design, I want to make it on the codebehind...

Comment: i saw that DoubleAnimationUsingPath on the xaml storyboard when i used the create motion path.... but i dont get it how can i pass or create the points created from <path> to DoubleAnimationUsingPath points.... any idea ?

Comment: can i pass the <path.data> to DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry? if it can how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a MatrixTransform as the Image's RenderTransform

```
<Canvas>
    <Path x:Name="k3_r2"
          StrokeThickness="3" StrokeDashArray="4 4" Stroke="Blue"
          Data="M570,190 L570,160 495,160 495,125 165,125 165,175"/>

    <Image x:Name="imgMan"
           Source="/wpfUsrControlTower1;component/DependentResources/man.png"
           Stretch="Fill" Height="30"
           Canvas.Left="-15" Canvas.Top="-15">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <MatrixTransform/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>
</Canvas>
```

you may use something like this:

```
var animation = new MatrixAnimationUsingPath
{
    PathGeometry = PathGeometry.CreateFromGeometry(k3_r2.Data),
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
};

imgMan.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(MatrixTransform.MatrixProperty, animation);
```

Comment: it works thank you so much...now i need fix the images when i enlarge the background it didnt follow the size....thanks again

Comment: how can i adjust the imgMan animation on its middle/center to the path animation?

Comment: Set a negative Margin, or negative values for the Canvas.Left and Top properties.